# jQuery DatePicker with today as maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to set today's date as a maxdate for jQuery datepicker in order to prevent users from picking date greater than today's date

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '0'});
```

This will set the maxDate to +0 days from the current date (i.e. today). See:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: @Alex Peattie one question to you I set the maxdate to maxDate: '-17y', and wanted to get the date 16+ and what am getting is 16+ but it excludes the next months started from current month.how I can solve this and have again 16+ years but all months.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+0m +0w' );
```

Answer (score 6):

In recent version, The following works fine:

```
    $('.selector').datetimepicker({
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
```

`maxDate` accepts a Date object as parameter.

The following found in documentation:

Multiple types supported:

- **Date:** A date object containing the minimum date.
- **Number:** A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
- **String:** A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a
  relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs;
  valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and
  "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven
  days from today.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bootstrap 3 date time picker, try this:

```
$('.selector').datetimepicker({ maxDate: $.now() });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who dont want to use datepicker method

```
var alldatepicker=  $("[class$=hasDatepicker]");

alldatepicker.each(function(){

var value=$(this).val();

var today = new Date();

var dd = today.getDate();

var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {

    dd='0'+dd

} 
if(mm<10) {

    mm='0'+mm

} 
today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
if(value!=''){
if(value>today){
alert("Date cannot be greater than current date");
}
}
});
```